# Realtime access to demographic data

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics shows demographic information about my visitors (like age, gender, interests).

Is there a way to get to this information for a specific visitor of a website(in real time) to show customized content? That information does not have to be exact (it just needs to be more correct than using just an average).

Is that information available trough SignIn with Google?

Or do I have to use the first name and picture (and some machine learning)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer the Google Analytics part of the question. Based on the current version of [Google Analytics Real Time Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/), none of the demographic dimensions are exposed, as part of the [available dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/).

If you look at the Google Analytics documentation about the cookies used, you can notice, that for [Google Analytics' Display Advertiser features](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=2700409), such as Demographics and Interest Reporting, a

> third-party DoubleClick cookie is used in addition to the other
> cookies.

There's no documentation available about this protocol, where this same demographic data could be accessed. Also, if you check this [support article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en) about the reports based on this data, you can see:

> Thresholds are applied to prevent anyone viewing a report from
> inferring the demographics or interests of individual users.

So it's not likely, that this data would be exposed on a per individual basis.

(I can't reply to the second part of your question about the Google Signin option, but I think that would anyway require the user to log in with a Google Account, so the whole concept is different to that of Google Analytics collected data.)